# Package is not in GOROOT

Tags: go

**main.go:5:2: package greetings is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\greetings)**

I am reading Head first go and it was written to create folder in c:/users/username/go/src/packagename and c:/users/username/go/src/project_name

when i try to run

`go run main.go` from project_name folder, i got the following error.
`main.go:5:2: package greetings is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\greetings)`

```
C:\Users\agriz>go env
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\agriz\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\agriz\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\agriz\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\agriz\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.16.7
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=NUL
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\agriz\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2047492330=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I dont want to keep the code in c drive. I want to run codes from D:/ is that possible? How can i do that?

Comment: Tip: Do not use go run file filename arguments.

Comment: :-( Just `dont use` is not helping me. Can you please tell me why? Do you mean to use `install` instead? If so, can you please explain why?

Comment: You compile Go code with go build and execute the generated executable. If you come from a scripting language and cannot endure the compilation step use `go run` or `go run .`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`set GO111MODULE=off` and `set GOPATH` to desired location is also working good.

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=off
```

and

```
set GOPATH=D:\go
```

This one fixed my problems.

Comment: can you explain why this works and what is problem with `GO111MODULE`?

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi I know this is late, but you can find the answer to that here, https://www.positioniseverything.net/package-is-not-in-goroot

Answer (score 6):

You can use go mod and explicitly give the path to the module you want to initialize.

From Documentation

> Init initializes and writes a new go.mod to the current directory, in
> effect creating a new module rooted at the current directory. The file
> go.mod must not already exist. If possible, init will guess the module
> path from import comments (see 'go help importpath') or from version
> control configuration. To override this guess, supply the module path
> as an argument.

Example

```
   'go mod init example.com/m' to initialize a v0 or v1 module
   'go mod init example.com/m/v2' to initialize a v2 module
```

Further details on how to setup your go-program can be found [here](https://golang.org/doc/code#Command).